# What type of resources should I plan for my postgres instance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am working on a production PostgreSQL driven application being hosted by Heroku and I do not know what type of resources I will need for my data.

A little about my data

I have 4 tables
Accounts

IDs

Addresses

Affils

Accounts is has many ID's, Accounts has many Addresses, Accounts has many Affills.

There will roughly be:

10 million + accounts

14 million + addresses

7 million + ID's

and 15 million + affils.

The queries being done on this will always be using a name on the account to filter, but it will be using either DMETAPHONE, or LEVENSHTEIN to do the matching. I was planning to index by name.

The Queries may look like this:

```sql
SELECT (rows) FROM accounts 
WHERE DMETAPHONE(name) = 'example' AND id IN 
    (SELECT accountID FROM addresses 
     WHERE (conditions)) AND id IN 
         (SELECT accountID FROM IDs 
          WHERE (conditions)).
```

For these types of operations what type of resources do I need to get good performance. Should I be looking at 2 GB of cache for the database, or should I be looking at 7.5GB, or maybe more? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You only need proper indexes and the disk space to contain the data and indexes. Nothing more. Note that you can create indexes in dmetaphone(name) and or levenshtein(name). The rest should be piece of cake for a vanilla postgres installation on mediocre hardware

Answer (score 1):

- DBs can always profit from more I/O. If you can get multiple file systems (which are on different physical disks, don't know how to go on about this on Heroku) you can distribute your DB objects using [tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtablespace.html). Experiment with either putting tables and their indexes on separated disks or having one disk for e.g. accounts + indexes and another for addresses + indexes.
- As foibs mentioned, [function results can be indexed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-expressional.html), this can give your use case a huge boost
- Postgres will make good use of all the memory you give to it (up to a point where you enter hugely oversized territory), put whatever you can into `shared_buffers` and make sure your `work_mem` is large enough that typical queries don't have to use disk files.
- If queries are slow, analyzing the SQL and optimizing it is usually a lot more efficient than just throwing hardware and money at the problem. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and [the pretty printer by Mr. "Depesz"](http://explain.depesz.com/) are your friend.